# Add Column to current DataTable with linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Can we add a new Column which is calculated Column in a existing DataTable

```
dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "a", "a1" });

dt1 = (from r in dt1.AsEnumerable()
select new {
col3 = r.Field<string>("col1") + r.Field<string>("col2") 
});
```

resulting DataTable should contain the new Column

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not via LINQ:

```
DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn();
col3.DataType = typeof(decimal); // or something suitable
col3.ColumnName = "sum";
col3.Expression = "col1 + col2";
dt1.Columns.Add(col3);
```

You can also use the LINQ approach to create a *projection*, but that isn't changing the table (so assigning to `dt1` is a mistake). Technically you could write an expression parser to write the `.Expression` for you, but I can't see that this would be a good investment of time.

Comment: Just to add LINQ - Language Integrated Query, as the title suggests is a mainly to perform queries and utilise the result as opposed to making 'alterations' to the initial dataset.

Comment: Is there any way to split using Expression. Like split with 'space'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution to reduce For/ForEach looping,

```
 dt1.Columns.Add("sum", typeof(System.Decimal));
 dt1.Columns["sum"].Expression = "'"+Col1+Col2+"'";
```

> > this would reduce looping time and updates quickly :) Kind of Marc's suggestion